# Хочу сделать программу, чтобы каждые три секунды делала фото с вебкамеры с помощью cv2. Только фото делается не каждые 3 секунды, а одновременно

Tags: python, время, cv2

вот код

```
import cv2

import time as tm

for m in range(1,4):

    tm.sleep(3)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

    for i in range(30):

        cap.read()

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    for q in range(1,4):

        cv2.imwrite("cam2"+ str(q) +".png", frame)   

        cap.release()
```

Comment: `cv2.waitKey(3000)`

Comment: спасибо проверю

Comment: результат тот же самый .на каждой секунде возле камеры ставлю разные предметы ,и пишутся только последних три кадра

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Comment: результат тот же(

Answer (score 1):

Ваш текущий код вообще делает что-то непонятное.

- 30 раз читает с камеры, никуда не помещая результат
- 3 раза подряд читает один и тот же кадр, сохраняя его в разные файлы

Может вы хотели сделать так:

```
import cv2
import time as tm

for m in range(1,4):
    tm.sleep(3)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imwrite("cam2"+ str(m) +".png", frame)   
    cap.release()
```

Comment: спасибо.Получилось

Comment: @max Тогда пометьте ответ галочкой как решение. Так же сделайте и в других вопросах, где проблема решена.